# Git Host Key verification failed

Tags: git

Sorry if this is a repeat question. I have reviewed similar questions and I am simply too new to understand the answers. Can someone please help a newbie resolve this issue with git in very simple terms. Trying to push to github I get the following error:

"Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

I just installed git on a new computer, everything was working fine on the other one, but now I cannot connect to github on either computer. I added new SSH key for the new computer but I still cant resolve it. Thought I would go back and try on the original computer but I get the same error message. What did I do wrong? Please!

Comment: May not matter, but what is your Operating System?

Comment: windows 7 professional

Comment: How did you install git and generate your SSH key? Did you add your key on Github? Have you read [Github's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-windows) on generating keys in Windows?

Comment: I installed git from a link our school gave us and generated the SSH key according to the instructions they gave us. It worked beautifully the first time on the first computer. I read through evrything on gitgub, but I just dont understand all the tech jargon.

Comment: Okay, well... Github's instructions are pretty straight since they tell you what to do step-by-step. Your error means Github can't verify your key, so I think you just need to add it to your account on Github. Alternatively, you could simply use the [Github Destkop Application](https://desktop.github.com/).

Comment: did add it to github, even got the verification email and see it in there with the new name I gave it. Thanks anyway